# What differentiates a population risk model versus Individual risk model?

Tags: classification, biostatistics, risk

I am trying to determine why people ask if a model of a health care risk (for inpatient stay, or acquiring a disease or any outcome) is a population risk model or an individual risk model. This is in a clinical setting where the outcome is some medical event and covariates are personal health history and demographics.  The risk here is then the $\text{prob}(\text{outcome})$ as determined by some binary classifier.

I understand there may be a different emphasis on the way quality of the model is assessed.  For an individual risk model it is perhaps more important to have a small variance of an individual's score and this measure is not captured by AUC of the model or other traditional accuracy measures. Is that the main reason for the difference?

If the model is created with observations of people's health history so rows in model are people, then is this necessarily an individual risk model?  If not why not?